# Registration-free COM-like interop and threading

Tags: c#, c++, windows, multithreading, com

I’m working on a desktop app that has WPF GUI and unmanaged C++ backend. 
I’ve defined API the following way (C# version, truncated):

```
[Guid( "###" ), InterfaceType( ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown )]
interface iMyApp
{
    void aMethod();
}
[DllImport( "my.dll", PreserveSig = true )]
public extern static int create( string configPath, out iMyApp a );
```

In the backend I have

```
__interface __declspec( uuid( "###" ) ) iMyApp: public IUnknown
{
    HRESULT __stdcall aMethod();
}
```

And classic ATL-based implementation.

This works nice and fast, requires no COM registration, no type libraries, no MIDL compiler,  etc.

The problem is, I can’t pass iMyApp instances across threads in C#, E_NOINTERFACE exception is raised.

My implementation is thread-neutral.

How to tell that to .NET so it stops marshalling my interfaces across threads, and just use the same IUnknown pointer on all threads? If it matters, I only need to support 4.5+

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1czb21wa.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant there’s no such option. Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise update 1 here. http://const.me/tmp/AtlSimpleObjectWizard.png

Comment: Surely you see the "Free-thread marshaler" checkbox?  The CLR has no way to discover your ThreadingModel since you did not register your component.  So select Both and let the FTM take care of the marshaling.

Comment: @HansPassant I didn't see the checkbox because some MSDN article says the free-threaded objects better be Neutral (since Win2K), and that checkbox’s disabled unless “Both”. However, I’ve already aggregated the FTM myself without wizard, works OK. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted by Hans Passant, the key here is [CoCreateFreeThreadedMarshaler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694500(v=vs.85).aspx) API.

Add a private variable `CComPtr<IUnknown> m_ftm;`

Initialize that marshaller:

```
HRESULT FinalConstruct()
{
    IUnknown* pUnk = GetUnknown();
    return CoCreateFreeThreadedMarshaler( pUnk, &m_ftm );
}
```

Process IID_IMarshal in QueryInterface, by adding the following line to the interface map:

```
COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY_AGGREGATE( IID_IMarshal, m_ftm )
```

After that, C# code will happily call those objects from any thread. Of course you'll have to handle synchronization yourself, [CComAutoCriticalSection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50yhb8t7.aspx) / [CComCritSecLock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33ydddb1.aspx) often help.

**Update:** MS broke my code in VS 2017, updated the answer. See edit history for VS2015 version.